# How to autoincrement global variable in jsonata

Tags: jsonata

```
(
    $find := function($object, $data) {(
        $count := 1;
        $each($object, function($v, $k){(
            $k in $data ? ($count := ($count + 1)): ''
        )})
    )};
)
```

Here **count** is always returning **2**, how to auto increment variable in jsonata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible in JSONata to reassign a value of a variable defined in a parent closure, meaning that the only way to deliver its increment from the inner closure to the outer closure is to return it from your function. $each is not supposed to return anything, but we can always use $reduce for that - something like below:

```
(
  $find := function($object, $data) {
    (
      $count := $reduce($keys($object), function($acc, $k) { 
        $k in $data ? ($acc + 1) : $acc
      }, 0);

      $count
    )
  };

  $find($, ["destination", "line_items"])
)
```

Interactive playground link: https://stedi.link/syBM3yM